# KDE Plasma - Terminal as wallpaper

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, kde

Can be possible having a terminal as a background / wallpaper? The alternatives I've searched suggest customizing the application with no borders and fullscreen resolution, but, that makes the configuration in all the terminals I want to open later.

I did the alternative, this is how my desktop looks:
[image: Desktop screenshot]

I'm using Arch Linux KDE Plasma with Kitty terminal.

Comment: One option might be using a different terminal for background. Whether that's suitable depends on what you want to use the background terminal for :-)

Comment: With respect, this is a to do list and so a computer solution like you want will be decidedly niche. Try a traditional to do list. That is what I do

Comment: That's a good Idea Peregrino69! Thanks!

Comment: You're right John, would be very practical too. This idea was for someone else but I didn't know how to do it, so, after researching a few hours I write a question. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching a few more hours I have a solution, using **xwinwrap**.

1. Download **xwinrap** with package manager.
2. Open terminal and start **xwinwrap** with this command (for example using mate terminal):

   - `xwinwrap -ov -fs -- /usr/libexec/mate-terminal/mate-terminal`
   - The path is where the terminal executable is located.
3. Once **xwinwrap** is started you can resize the window, adjust position, change transparency, etc...
4. For making the window as background, open settings and establish xwinrap to start automatically on start.